# Docker X11 Forwarding Security

Tags: ssh, virtualization, openssh, docker, x11

I am currently running a Docker container with a program with a GUI forwarded over SSH (using X forwarding over OpenSSH). The virtualized server has X11Forwarding enabled and I can connect to it from my host machine and open up an application from it without much of a problem.

Is this secure? Does this give the sandboxed system/application access to the host in any way? How am I exposing my system to the possibly untrustworthy application? Is the system that is connecting over SSH exposing its entire X display session to the virtual machine?

I'm aware it's able to pick up keystrokes and other things even whilst tucked away into the background (minimized to KDE taskbar/tray), as applications such as Skype proved, but I would like to know if this extends beyond that, such as direct system access in any form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a general basis, you should *not* forward X11 display from *untrusted* environments to your local environment. X11 is an old technology which was not conceived with security in mind from the beginning, on the contrary it was designed to allow every application to communicate with each other.

Was does "*communicate*" mean? As you said, it could grasp you keystrokes. It could also take screenshots. It could interact with other windows, inject keystrokes, mouse moves, etc., etc., etc.. Well, I guess you got it: allowing an untrusted system to export X11 display to your local server is a bit like passing your screen, keyboard and mouse to this untrusted system. You are right in the sense it may not be able to access your local files directly, but it will be nearly equivalent.

Some work has been done in order to mitigate the risk though. X11 indeed include a distinction between a trusted and untrusted clients. An untrusted client *should* be confined in a subset of actions designed to prevent most of the nefarious actions described above.

SSH integrates this mode, even if some Linux distribution disable it and consider all X11 client as trusted for the end-user convenience (!). You may want to check the `ForwardX11` and `ForwardX11Trusted` parameters in your SSH client configuration files:

- `ForwardX11` tells if X11 is enabled by default when you establish an SSH connection (you must use the `-x` (lower-case 'x') command-line parameter to disable it on-demand),
- `ForwardX11Trusted` tells if, when you enable X11 forwarding, the client will be automatically considered as trusted. **I strongly recommend you to put this one to `no`**.

When `ForwardX11Trusted` is set to `no`, the `ssh` command will offer you to select the trust level for your session:

- The `-X` command-line parameter will consider the client as unsecure, this is recommended way to go.
- The `-Y` command-line parameter will consider the client as secure, this is only needed for very specific use-cases and should be used with care since you must consider that the remote applications will have a full access to your system.

However, as I stated above, you should not rely on the security feeling provided by the `-X` "secure" mode to export display from untrusted environment to your local X server. But this should be sane enough if you consider this Docker environment as a trusted environment.

GUI application isolation is a domain under heavy study currently. While every other of the Linux system has went through large hardening measures until now, I have the impression that X was nearly always left appart, too large and complex to really evolve and be adapted to current needs, but leaving now a nasty weakness.

Secure platforms like [Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) which is precisely relying on a set of isolated Xen VM exporting X display to a Dom0 domain went through the pain to develop their own X protocol "reverse-proxy" between the X clients and server to ensure the server's security. I do not know any standalone equivalent of such technology, but you may find interesting ideas here: [Best method to sandbox X applications in ubuntu](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/56703/32746). X server is leaving his last times and ought to be replaced by a more modern and secure alternative as soon as such alternatives become ready (see [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29) and [Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_%28software%29) for instance), but until then at least check to who you entrust your desktop!

Comment: Wow! I was not expecting this elaborate of an answer, thank you! I was more concerned with the application (e.g., Skype) being able to reach out of the bounds of sanity and being able to browse my local filesystem. However, the ability for the application to basically have some relatively powerful control over my X session is a little worrying, so I'll have to end up figuring out another way to isolate it.

Thank you once again. :)

Answer (score 2):

To run GUI applications in docker and circumvent X security leaks, I have published [x11docker on github](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker).

The main idea is to run a second X server with its own authentication cookies. docker containers get access to the new X server and are segregated from display :0.

Answer (score 0):

What you essentially did was to display a remote (in your case - dockerized) application on your local X server.

This is not different form displaying such an application form any remote server, which is as secure as `X11` is (so no access to your local host).

The application indirectly uses your local host (though `docker`) but this is a sandboxed environment (`docker` vulnerabilities aside). It has the ability, however, to for instance write files on your disk (by writing them on its virtualized filesystem, which is then translated to files on your host)